# How to put comma inside one list words of menu

Tags: html, css

Hello I can't find the solutions over googling.

then the "Phone number" shift to the next line.
like this one

"Sign up"   "Home"    "Contact, Phone number
=> move the next line"

My question is how to align the Contact, Phone number in the one line as a menu list. Thanks

```css
.nav-li {
  display: block;
  padding: 20px 30px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav-links">
  <li class="nav-li">
    <!-- svelte-ignore a11y-invalid-attribute -->
    <a href="#">Sign up</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-li">
    <!-- svelte-ignore a11y-invalid-attribute -->
    <a href="#">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-li">
    <!-- svelte-ignore a11y-invalid-attribute -->
    <a href="#">Contact, Phone number</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Add a break => `<a href="#">Contact,<br> Phone number</a>`

Comment: sorry, my question was how to not moved the next line. Just in one menu list like "Contact, Phone number". It's automatically moved to the next line when I see on browser.

Comment: @Bilguun Enkhee You can use border-bottom: 1px solid #00f; and make text-decoration:none for links.

Comment: @BilguunEnkhee I think, your question isn't clear. Could you attach a screenshot of your result and desired result?

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/0bc7azed/3/

either use `<p>`
or

```
<br>
```

code

```
  <ul class="nav-links" >
             <li class="nav-li">
                 <!-- svelte-ignore a11y-invalid-attribute -->
                 <a href="#">Sign up</a>
             </li>
             <li class="nav-li">
                   <!-- svelte-ignore a11y-invalid-attribute -->
                 <a href="#">Home</a>
             </li>
             <li class="nav-li">
                   <!-- svelte-ignore a11y-invalid-attribute -->
                 <a href="#">Contact,<br>Phone number</a>
             </li>
         </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `<br>` tag to break the line. You can also check answer by @FiveFour_Xone

```css
.nav-li {
  display: block;
  padding: 20px 30px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav-links">
  <li class="nav-li">
    <!-- svelte-ignore a11y-invalid-attribute -->
    <a href="#">Sign up</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-li">
    <!-- svelte-ignore a11y-invalid-attribute -->
    <a href="#">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-li">
    <!-- svelte-ignore a11y-invalid-attribute -->
    <a href="#">Contact, <br />Phone number</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

**I hope, this might help you.**

```css
.nav-li{
  display: block;
  padding: 20px 30px;

}
.nav-li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #00f;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <ul class="nav-links" >
             <li class="nav-li">
                 <!-- svelte-ignore a11y-invalid-attribute -->
                 <a href="#">Sign up</a>
             </li>
             <li class="nav-li">
                   <!-- svelte-ignore a11y-invalid-attribute -->
                 <a href="#">Home</a>
             </li>
             <li class="nav-li">
                   <!-- svelte-ignore a11y-invalid-attribute -->
                 <a href="#">Contact, Phone number</a>
             </li>
         </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can use span tag in a tag and set the attribute for span to display: block.
If you use br it will be more difficult to customize**

```css
  .nav-li {
      display: block;
      padding: 20px 30px;
    }

  .nav-li span {
    display: block;
  }
```

```html
    <ul class="nav-links">
      <li class="nav-li">
        <!-- svelte-ignore a11y-invalid-attribute -->
        <a href="#">Sign up</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-li">
        <!-- svelte-ignore a11y-invalid-attribute -->
        <a href="#">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-li">
        <!-- svelte-ignore a11y-invalid-attribute -->
        <a href="#">
          <span>Contact</span>
          <span>Phone number</span>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
```